# How to get a UIView from a UIViewController without adding the controller to the view hierarchy and making it visible?

Tags: iphone, overlay, xib, nib

I want to avoid laying out a view programmatically.

I want to only use a NIB file to do such work.

The problem is that the only way that I know of bringing a NIB file to life is via a controller like so:

```
ZBarReaderViewController* reader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
ScannerOverlayViewController *sovc =
[[ScannerOverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScannerOverlayView" bundle:nil];
reader.cameraOverlayView = sovc.view;
```

But this approach doesn't work out so well because stepping through the debugger shows that the views is 0x0 or Nil.

Now this may be because the controller is never added-to/displayed-on the view hierarchy and I'm trying to get a view out of it in order to recycle it as an "overlay view" on another controller that allows me to specify it.

Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished without writing the View programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load view from XIB file:

```
// I assume, that there is only one root view in interface file
NSString *nibName = @"CustomView";
NSArray *loadedObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil];
UIView *view = [loadedObjects lastObject];
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. Is the loaded view returned as auto-released?

Comment: Yes, if you want to own it, you need to retain it.